# Concatenate the strings from a Crossjoin in MDX

Tags: mdx

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Page Views]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {
    Crossjoin({[Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].Members}, 
              {[Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour].Members})
          } ON ROWS
FROM [All Facts]
```

Is code to get the page views per weekday. It currently returns data like this:

> Sunday
>   ......0 - 198273
>   ......1 - 123987
>   ......2 - 128372
>   ......3 - 1283712

for each hour, for each day.
How do I get this to concatenate the strings from the crossjoin, so that it returns:

> Sunday 0 - 198273
>   Sunday 1 - 123987
>   Sunday 2 - 128372
>   Sunday 3 - 1283712

Or must this be created as a totally new measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
> WITH MEMBER [Measures].[pretty hour] AS [Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].CurrentMember.name || " " || [Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour].CurrentMember.name 
>   SELECT    
>   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[pretty hour], [Measures].[Page Views]} ON COLUMNS,   
>   NON EMPTY {    
>       Crossjoin({[Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].Members},     
>                 {[Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour].Members})   
>             } ON ROWS   
>FROM [All Facts]
```

You have to ignore the row headers, but it produces the result I wanted! :) @icCube had the right-ish idea, just Mondrian needed || instead of +, and "CurrentMember.name" instead of just "name"

Comment: nice I was of some help, a small up is allways appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm a bit un a hurry but you can use [mdx calculated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html) to generate the string:

```
 With
  Member MyOutput AS [Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].name + " " + [Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour] + " " + STR( ([Measures].[Page Views]) )
 SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[MyOutput]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {
    Crossjoin({[Date Dim.Weekday Hierarchy].[Weekday].Members}, 
          {[Time Dimension.Time Hierarchy].[Hour].Members})
      } ON ROWS
  FROM [All Facts]
```

Comment: I tried changing Member MyOutput to Member [Measures].[MyOutput], but still no luck.

Comment: Sure, here are the error messages. "Hierarchy for calculated member '[MyOutput]' not found" for your original post; then after I changed MyOutput to [Measures].[MyOutput] it says: No function matches signature '<String> + <String>'

Comment: what olap server are you using (it's not SSAS or icCube)? -- can you try with a simple string concatenation -> MyOutput as "Toto" + " more Toto" ... the issue is how to concatenate strings with your server

Comment: I'm using Mondrian, so just found out that || is used for concatenation. However, this now produces:

Comment: Sunday | 0 | Weekday Hour 2983743.0 ; so it is retrieving the words "Weekday" and "Hour" rather than actually getting the specific name of the weekday or hour.

Comment: Matthew, I've no experience with Mondrian, sorry. Play a bit with the key and the functions you've available. After you can allways set properties in members with the values you're looking for.

Comment: if the key is a time, you might get what you're looking for if there is something like DateToString with a formatter...